# How stop macro on the end document?

Tags: vba, loops, ms-word, exit

I'm just learning and don't know much yet.
I wrote incorrect code

```
Sub sierotkiTXT_select()

    Do
 
        Selection.EndKey Unit:=wdLine
        Selection.MoveLeft Unit:=wdCharacter, Count:=3, Extend:=wdExtend

        If Selection.Text Like "* [aAwWzZiIoOuUVQ] *" Or Selection.Text Like "*[A-Z]. *" Or Selection.Text Like "* [a-z]. *" Or Selection.Text Like "*z. *" Or Selection.Text Like "*:] *" Then

            Result = MsgBox("OK?", vbYesNoCancel + vbQuestion)

            If Result = vbYes Then

                Selection.MoveRight Unit:=wdCharacter, Count:=1
                Selection.MoveLeft Unit:=wdCharacter, Count:=1
                Selection.Delete
                Selection.InsertAfter Text:=ChrW(160)
                
            End If
            
            If Result = vbCancel Then
            
                Exit Sub
 
            End If
            
        End If
    
        Selection.MoveRight Unit:=wdCharacter, Count:=3
      
    Loop Until Selection.Text = ActiveDocument.Range.Characters.Last

End Sub
```

and don't know how to stop such a macro at the end of the document (break the loop) without using a

```
Loop Until Selection.Text = ActiveDocument.Range.Characters.Last
```

It wouldn't be a problem, but the macro sometimes stops at the end-of-paragraph characters, interpreting them as the end of the document.
[EDIT]
Ok-ActiveDocument.Range.Characters.Last
Still returns empty - that's why it stops. I should not use this.

Examples (main text):
[before](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7i1Dy.jpg)

After run macro:
[after](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7C4Bw.jpg)

Examples (Endnotes):
[before](https://i.stack.imgur.com/p4fEU.jpg)
[after](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rwdXs.jpg)

Comment: What are trying to achieve with your code.

Comment: I am trying to add non-breaking space to some characters at the end of each line. I don't want to do this throughout the text, because it destroys the justification of the text. So using the macro I move some characters, but ONLY at the ends of the lines.

Comment: Like in your last post: Use the built-in tools like the .Find-Object or something else. If you use Selection and Loop/For you have to check for your own, when to stop. In this case, you would have to define a maximum (like all chracters possible to check) and set a couter which increases for every loop instance.

Comment: That's your solution, adding non breaking spaces.  What are you trying to do by adding non breaking spaces.

Comment: Improve the document's appearance by moving the vowels (and other signs) to the next line. In 2 places-main text and Endnotes.

Comment: And now can you provide examples of the text before and how you want it to look after your code has run. Edit your original post to add this information and that from your previous reply.

Comment: Not knowing how else to do it, for now I used a childish method.
I manually add "some unused character" at the end of the text or endnotes and in the macro line:
Loop Until Selection.Text = " some unused character " so that I exit the loop at the end of the document.

Answer (score 0):

You don't even need a macro for this! All you need is two *wildcard* Find/Replace opertions, one with:

```
Find = (<[A-Za-z])^32
Replace = \1^s
```

and one with:

```
Find = (<[a-z].)^32
Replace = \1^s
```

See also: https://www.msofficeforums.com/word-vba/48717-how-i-find-character-line.html

Comment: No. No. No.  Again: I am trying to add non-breaking space to some characters at the end of each line. I don't want to do this throughout the text, because it destroys the justification of the text. So using the macro I move some characters, but ONLY at the ends of the lines.

Comment: Given that non-breaking spaces have the same variable-width characteristic as normal spaces in all modern versions of Word, your «it destroys the justification of the text» objection is unfounded.

Comment: Check: https://i.stack.imgur.com/6V2gr.jpg

Comment: See: https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/all/nonbreakable-space-justification-in-word-2016/4fa1ad30-004c-454f-9775-a3beaa91c88b#:~:text=If%20you%20want%20a%20variable-width%20non-breaking%20space%2C%20you,Do%20you%20know%20why%20it%20works%20like%20that%3F

Comment: I read through this thread and finally found the answer:
"If you are experiencing fixed-width nonbreaking spaces in Word 2016, the likelihood is that you are dealing with a legacy document (in Compatibility Mode)." This is true in my case, because I am working on an old document written in WORD 2007 (without patches installed-which also caused other problems, e.g. sticking words together after opening in WORD 2019).

Answer (score 0):

I corrected my code and it works.

```
Sub sierotkiTXT_select()

'szukaj sierotek

    Dim NumLines As Long
        Application.ScreenUpdating = True
       Selection.EndKey Unit:=wdStory, Extend:=wdExtend  
NumLines = Selection.Range.ComputeStatistics(wdStatisticLines)
  MsgBox "Lines to check " & (NumLines)
  Selection.Collapse
For i = 1 To NumLines
    Selection.EndKey Unit:=wdLine
    Selection.MoveLeft Unit:=wdCharacter, Count:=3, Extend:=wdExtend
   If Selection.Text Like "* [aAwWzZiIoOuUVQ] *" Or Selection.Text Like "*[A-Z]. *" Or Selection.Text Like "* [a-z]. *" Or Selection.Text Like "*z. *" Or Selection.Text Like "*:] *" Then
      Result = MsgBox("Akceptujesz?", vbYesNoCancel + vbQuestion)
 If Result = vbYes Then
      Selection.MoveRight Unit:=wdCharacter, Count:=1
      Selection.MoveLeft Unit:=wdCharacter, Count:=1
      Selection.Delete
      Selection.InsertAfter Text:=ChrW(160)
 End If
          If Result = vbCancel Then
    Exit Sub
 End If
    End If
   Selection.MoveRight Unit:=wdCharacter, Count:=3
Next

End Sub
```

Comment: Using Selection is an awful, inefficient, way of doing things. I included a link showing how to process the document without that. Moreover, your code will not process the whole document - if run in the document body, it will not process footnotes or endnotes, for example.

Comment: You are right, the selection method is slow, but this way you can see what characters are checked, whether the script works, on which characters the macro crashes. Yes the macro does not work on the whole document-this is not a problem you can always manually click on footnotes and run. Besides, for footnotes I have a slightly reworked macro looking for other characters. Of course it can be done in 1 script, but I am just learning.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I found that I can use the Search/Replace function instead of the macro BUT instead of inserting EVERY hard space after a, i, o, u, w, z (which in my case makes the aligned text look bad and moves all the text unnecessarily), I can use

Search:

space([aAwWzZiIoOuU])space

Replace with:
space\1ZERO WIDTH JOINERspace

Where ZERO WIDTH JOINER is Unicode Character U+200D.
How to type in Microsoft Windows: Alt + (on NumPad Keyboard) 08205

ZERO WIDTH JOINER looks like this in WORD (with the "Show hidden characters" option enabled):
[ZERO WIDTH JOINER image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Mj4zt.jpg)

And here is an example of how the text looked in my case after using a hard space and after using a ZERO WIDTH JOINER+spacebar:
[Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hNkzj.jpg)